# shell:(foldername) doesn't work

Tags: shell, windows-rt

I've accidentally deleted two of my user folders - Pictures and Videos on Windows RT 8.1. I've restored them using registration entries. The folders are restored but when I try to search for the folders using shell:(foldername) which means shell:pictures and shell:videos, they don't work at all. This also happens for the Documents folder and when I search for shell:documents, it doesn't work either. I did not delete the documents folder at all. Is there something wrong with my laptop and how can this be fixed? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What do you mean by `shell:documents`? Typing documents into command prompt, or the Windows Search? What happens when you just type `Pictures`?

Comment: When I press windows key + R, the run window appears and when I type shell:searches, for example, and press enter, windows should direct me to the searches folder. This method works for every user folder except music, documents, pictures and videos.

Comment: Just type pictures and see what happens. Im not sure where you got the shell: thing from, Windows will open the files with the appropriate program (in this case, the explorer.exe shell)

Comment: Thank you. I will try typing pictures and see what happens

Comment: Ok typing "pictures" actually worked and I've also figured out that videos is actually shell:my video. thanks a lot! 

Answer (score 1):

shell:documents is actually `shell:personal`
shell:pictures is actually `shell:my pictures`
shell:videos is actually `shell:my videos`